# Tkinter placing Image into Frame, background

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter, frame

Screen: [image: Screen]

Firstly,I have got problem with the white background of my Frame because it expand beyond LabelFrame. Secondly, I would like image to be in the middle of my Frame.

```
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(filename))
panel.image = img
panel.configure(image=img)

ImageFrame = LabelFrame(page1, text="Podgląd", height=200, width=300, background='white')
ImageFrame.grid(row=0, column=3, pady=10, padx=5)
panel = Label(ImageFrame)
panel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NESW')
ImageFrame.grid_propagate(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `LabelFrame` contains the label, and you have given it the bg color "white". If you just want the interior to be white you can do that by inserting a new `Frame` with `bg='white'`, then put the image there.

Then; to place the image in the middle you have to tell `grid()` to expand tha cell to fill the available area with `columnconfigure()` and `rowconfigure()`. See my example below:

```
from tkinter import *

page1 = Tk()

ImageFrame = LabelFrame(page1, text="Podgląd", height=200, width=300)
ImageFrame.grid(row=0, column=3, pady=10, padx=5)
ImageFrame.grid_propagate(0)            # Stops geometry propagation
ImageFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # Expands cell to fill available space
ImageFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)    # --- " ---

whiteframe = Frame(ImageFrame, bg='white')  # For white background
whiteframe.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew', padx=5, pady=5)
whiteframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # Expands cell to fill available space
whiteframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)    # --- " ---

img = PhotoImage(file='images/beer.png')
panel = Label(whiteframe, image=img)
panel.image = img
panel.grid(row=0, column=0)

page1.mainloop()
```